# search for exact word in hybris solr

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to make the product search return only the exact word in hybris with solr, but even leaving only the free text query search activated from the name property it still searches with a character missing at the end sometimes.

I hope when searching for "ca" it doesn't return anything, when searching for "car" it returns red car and doesn't return cart

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.